# Writing to Windows EventLog from arbitrary source

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows, event-log

I'm trying to write to the Windows EventLog from different sources to recreate a series of events on my system. The idea is that I could take the Event's XML and recreate that in the EventLog. So far I've figured out how to create a simple event from an arbitrary provider based on Source name by `EventLog.WriteEntry("Service Control Manager", "a test message", EventLogEntryType.Information, 7036, 0);` but that's only a classic log, which doesn't support the more advanced data structure that I need to mimic a modern log. I've tried using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.EventProvider.WriteEvent, but that only works for some provider GUIDs (I can get it to work for the Power-Troubleshooter but not the Service Control Manager for example). I haven't been able to find anything on the internet and I've been searching for a few days, would be really helpful if anyone knew any way to do this - in c# or not.

```
 using System;  
 using System.Collections.Generic;  
 using System.Linq;  
 using System.Text;  
 using System.Diagnostics.Eventing;
 using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ETWDemo  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {
            //This writes a simple message event
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Service Control Manager", "a basic message", EventLogEntryType.Information, 7036, 0);

            //The rest of this writes a modern EventLog
            //this is the GUID for the Service Control Manager
            var eventProvider = new EventProvider(new Guid("{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}"));
            if (eventProvider.IsEnabled())
                Console.WriteLine("Provider is enabled");
                //Outputs 'True' on my system
            EventDescriptor eventDescriptor;
            unchecked
            {
                eventDescriptor = new EventDescriptor(
                    7036, //EventId
                    0, //Version
                    0x0, //Channel Id
                    0x4, //Level
                    0x0, //OpCode
                    0x0, //Task
                    (long)0x8000000000000000); //Keywords
            }
            var wroteOk = eventProvider.WriteEvent(ref eventDescriptor, "pls", "wrk");
            if (wroteOk)
                Console.WriteLine("Claims to have written correctly");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Did not write correctly");
            //Console outputs "Claims to have written correctly", but nothing changes in the eventLog
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using the windows event log? Are you not allowed to use something like log4net...?? For logging...??

Comment: I'm using EventLogs because I have software loaded on the computers I want to run this on that's already configured to read the EventLogs and analyze them. The program I'm trying to create would be used to test and demonstrate this software.

Comment: hence the whole purpose of _mimicing_ the EventLogs